# Django: download created zip from function. Zipfile returns empty/not an zip-archive file

Tags: python, django, download, zip, httpresponse

I am trying to give the user a "Save as" option when the user clicks the download button in my Django app. When the user clicks the button it kicks-off the following function. The function gets some CSVs from a blob container in Azure and adds them to a zip. That zip should then be offered to download and store in a location of the user's choice.

```
def create_downloadable_zip():
    container_client = az.container_client(container_name=blob_generator.container_name)
    blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

    zip_file = zipfile.ZipFile(f'{models.AppRun.client_name}.zip', 'w')



    for blob in blobs:
        if blob.name.endswith(".csv"):
            downloaded_blob = container_client.download_blob(blob)
            blob_data = downloaded_blob.readall()

            zip_file.writestr(blob.name, blob_data)

    zip_file.close()

    return zip_file
```

My views.py looks like follow:

```
def download_file(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        zip = create_downloadable_zip()

        response = HttpResponse(zip, content_type='application/zip')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachement;' f'filename={zip}.zip'

        return response

    #
    # else:
    #     # return a 404 response if this is a POST request
    #     return HttpResponse(status=404)

    return render(request, "download_file.html")
```

The functionality works, but it returns an empty non-zip file when the "Save as" window pop-ups. However, the actual zip file contains the files is being saved in the root folder of the Django project.

I really don't get why I doesn't return the zip file from memory, but rather directly stores that zip file in root and returns an empty non-zip file with the download functionality.

Someone knows what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `zip_file` is nothing more than a zipfile object. After closing it is not associated with the zipfile anymore, so you're not returning it. Instead, it's writing to the path you've provided, which is in the root directory of your project. You would need to read the contents in your `download_file` function to send it as a response.

Comment: Side note: I would not recommend naming variables the same as built-in functions. Maybe something like `request_zip` would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`zipfile` is used to open a file, but it is not the actual file, simply a zipfile object as @b-remmelzwaal mentioned. You will need to create a file like object, and return that instead. This can be done using `io.BytesIO`.

```py
from io import BytesIO
from zipfile import ZipFile

def create_zip():
    container_client = az.container_client(container_name=blob_generator.container_name)
    blobs = container_client.list_blobs()

    buffer = BytesIO()

    with ZipFile(buffer, 'w') as zip_file:
        for blob in blobs:
            if blob.name.endswith(".csv"):
                downloaded_blob = container_client.download_blob(blob)
                blob_data = downloaded_blob.readall()

                zip_file.writestr(blob.name, blob_data)

    return buffer.getvalue()
```

Note we are returning the file like object, not the zip file object. This is because `buffer` represents the actual file you've created.

You don't have to use a context manager, but I find them very useful.

Also, check your spelling for the line:

```py
# attachment instead attachement
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment;' f'filename={zip}.zip'
```

[BytesIO Documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO)